# How do I get koa-router to match the routes correctly

Tags: node.js, typescript, koa, koa-router

So I'm working with [`koa`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa) and [`koa-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-router)

I have an api that uses mongo as database, and I have a few endpoints setup like this:

```js
const router = new Router({ sensitive: false });

router.get(`/author`, controller.getAuthors);
router.get(`/author/:authorId`, controller.getAuthorById);
router.get(`/author/:authorId/books`, controller.getAuthorBooks);
```

However when I run a `GET` on `/author/:authorId/books` I see this error in my logs:

```
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

and the string that is being passed on to Mongo to search for the author is this:

```
oTKGdrJXo4aUVj9ZC22MMLeA7Z03/books
```

So `koa-router` is routing to `/author/:authorId` with the full path including the `/books`.

How do I prevent this?

I know that if I register the more specifics endpoints first it works, but I don't want to have to worry about the order in which I register my endpoints, it makes for a very fragile solution

**EDIT**

Adding implementation of `getAuthorById`:

```js
public async getAuthorById(ctx: Context): Promise<void> {
  if (ctx.params.authorId) {
    const author = await this.authorService.findById(ctx.params.authorId);
    ctx.status = 200;
    ctx.body = author;
  } else {
    ctx.status = 404;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that extracts the 'authorId' part? Probably the `controller.getAuthorBooks` function.

Comment: Sure, I'll add a snippet, but keep in mind that `getAuthorBooks` never gets invoked, that's actually the behavior that I want to reach

Comment: I misunderstood then. In that case, it's pretty strange. I don't see the same behavior. The reason I asked for getAuthorBooks is that I thought perhaps something went wrong there instead, which may have lead you to the wrong conclusion. But if you're sure getAuthorId gets called, then I don't know.

Comment: I don't see the same behavior either.  I am able get to the correct routes.